# Have issues with Java splitting with given line of words

Tags: java, split

```
String cityStateZip = ResultSetHelper.getString(resultSet, "line_3_addr"); // PU ABCDEF, CS 12345
if (StringHelper.isValid(cityStateZip)) {
    String[] splited = cityStateZip.split("\\s+");

    if (splited[0].length() > 0) {
        String city = splited[0].substring(0, splited[0].length() - 1);
        super.setFieldValue(OFFICECITY, city);  //PU
    }

    if (splited[1].length() > 0) {
        super.setFieldValue(OFFICEST, splited[1]); //ABCDEF
    }

    if (splited[2].length() > 0 ) {
        super.setFieldValue(OFFICEZIP, splited[2]); // CS 12345
    }
}
```

Comment: Words string that need to convert as per snipet is // PU ABCDEF, CS 12345

Comment: My Output is comming here  "PU ABCDEF, CS" but i need my O/p here PU ABCDEF, CS 12345

Comment: Since here string entered is containing 4 spaces in words so putput is not comming as expected i wanted to split last two words in one string ......                   if (splited[2].length() > 0 ) {
        super.setFieldValue(OFFICEZIP, splited[2]); // CS 12345

Comment: There is also a space between CS and 12345, so they get split into two items, not one

Comment: Yes , Heare is space between CS 12345 , but i want to print this both into one substring, rest will be as it is. any idea how can we do ? any ways i have inserted inside last condition splited[2]=splited[2]+ splited[3];  but that may though some where Null pointer exception

Comment: Are you sure that your last part will always contain a 5 digit number, If that is the case we can split it with some regex. Let me know if that's what you wanted

Comment: Please edit your question to refelct your changes to the code and to include the input, current output and expected output at the very least. Some explaining text might also be helpful. If there is an error, also include the all error information (codes/stacktrace/...)

Comment: Yes At this point of time, because this proj for US. zip code will be mostly 5 digit only, i Believe.